# Flutter Security

Tags: flutter, dart, https, jwt

I am creating a Flutter app which uses Node Js server API. For the authorization I decided to use JWT with private/public keys. Communication between Server and mobile client uses HTTPS. Flutter app stores the token in a keychain (ios) or a keystore (android). My question is related to the need of the additional security measures implementations. I am wondering if the following points are required:

1. Verification of the server responses with public key by checking the token to identify the server
2. Verification of the client requests with the private key on the server side (client signs the token with public key)

Are these really needed in order to avoid man in the middle attacs? My objection is related to the performance related to signing/verifying tokens for each communication.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've used JWT our mobile apps for security and these apps had taken the security test(3.party company). The company says: secret your stored token or any keys.

And we know doesn't enough just JWT security. We wrote a custom encrypted algorithm to hide JWT (like sha-1) so we encrypt JWT to this.( you must write encryption code  client-side & backend side)
Normal jwt : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

After encriypt: xxs{4=-23dasdxe3 (example)

We passed the security rules with this solution.

Comment: Thank you. Do you use the same encryption algorithm for each client? Is it not easy to crack/boot the app on the mobile device and find/understand the algorithm?

Comment: All right, find it algorithm but my algorithm work base present and always change all request so even though it is found, we are shortening JWT expiration time.

Comment: Thank you. In this case it seems like you are sending the JWT when the user is logged in together with the algorithm method. As I understand you are storing the JWT and the algorithm method on the server side (database), right? This is smart. Do you change the algorithm for each JWT or based on a time manner? Which party is hashing the JWT, server or client?